# How to rewrite this nested SQL query to make it faster?

Tags: php, mysql, query-performance

this query return 16000 records and takes about 3-4 minutes! I added LIMIT 10 at the end of the query but it made no difference.

UPDATE: here is explain output:
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
$sql = "
        SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(`firstName`,' ',`lastName` SEPARATOR '<br/>') AS `users` 
        from (SELECT `frk_item`.`itemId`,`frk_quotes`.`quoteId`,`frk_item`.`title`,`quoteno`,`gmp`,`value`,`values`,`status`,`dates`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`name`,`frk_quoteuser`.`userid` 
        FROM `frk_item` INNER JOIN `frk_quotes` ON `frk_item`.`itemId` = `frk_quotes`.`itemId` 
        LEFT JOIN `frk_project` ON `frk_project`.`projectId` = `frk_item`.`projectId` 
        LEFT JOIN `frk_quoteuser` ON `frk_quoteuser`.`quoteId`=`frk_quotes`.`quoteId` 
        LEFT JOIN `frk_member` ON `frk_member`.`memberId` = `frk_quoteuser`.`userId` 
        WHERE `frk_quotes`.`varis`='original' AND `frk_quotes`.`status`!='0'" . $filter . "  
        order by `frk_item`.`quoteno` DESC) as `poop` 
        GROUP BY `quoteId` 
        ORDER BY `quoteno` DESC";
```

UPDATE:
Rick James advice of adding indexes resolved the issue. it is now taking 2-3 seconds to load the records

Comment: What does the `explain` of that query show?

Comment: Thanks for editing it Paul. Sorry what do you mean by explain?

Comment: [Understanding MySQL Queries With EXPLAIN](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-mysql-queries-with-explain)

Comment: Note the 2 tables that show `ALL` in the type column ... can you add the table structure for those 2 tables to the end of the question?

Comment: Thanks, I should have added to my previous comment, need to see the portion that also shows the indexes for both tables. It may be easier to add the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName` for both tables instead of a picture.

Comment: Please read this, esp. the section on query performance. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 Then please [edit] your question to give the info we need to help you.

Comment: Please share the table structure in usable form (as text, not as images!)

Comment: Why the limit doesn't speed up things is simple - limit is done at the end of the query in this case. You use limit when you transfer data over the network, so you don't throttle your bandwidth and get some results quickly - however, the rest of the query gets executed before that. Without knowing more about the size of your tables and indexing, it is impossible to give you any feasible advice besides what was already said - use "EXPLAIN" command to help you understand the bottlenecks in your query.

Comment: I think you may have missed some of the content of the post linked to you by O.Jones. You've added images, not text. You're effectively asking users to transcribe your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Switch from MyISAM to InnoDB.
- What is `$filter`?
- How many different value of `status`?  If only two, then change to `AND status = 1`.
- `frk_quotes`: Add `INDEX(varis, status, quoteId, itemId)`
- `frk_quoteuser` needs `INDEX(quoteId, userId)`
- This seems to be useless: LEFT JOIN  `frk_member`  ON `frk_member`.`memberId` = `frk_quoteuser`.`userId`.  Don't include it if you don't need it.
- Remove the *inner* `ORDER BY`; it does nothing useful.
- Please qualify each column.
- The `(4)` on `INT(4)` means nothing.  See `TINYINT` and its siblings.
- Since the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are different, there is probably a second sort.
- `LIMIT 10` is useless because there is no way to design a single index that handles the `WHERE` *and* `GROUP BY` *and* `ORDER BY`.  That is all the work is done, then 10 rows are delivered.  This saves network traffic, but not any work before that.

Fix what you can of those, then come back for more critique, if needed.

Comment: Thank you. Adding two indexes fixed the performance issue. Indexes dropped the load time from 3-4 minutes to 2-3 seconds

Comment: Sometimes INDEXing is that spectacular.  (But not always.)